# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. After implementation okhttp3

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle, okhttp

Everything was working fine before adding okhttp3.

Build.Gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.retrofitneco'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.retrofitneco"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"

    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.11"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp3:4.7.2"

}
```

settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}
rootProject.name = "RetrofitNeco"
include ':app'
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx3ZN.jpg)

I have tried various methods to solve the problem, I have changed the version of okhttp3, I have switched Toggle offline mode on and off. I also changed in settings.gradle:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() //here
    }
}
```

but still the same error. I was expecting this change to cause at least another error.